# Geoserver SQL view parameterizing

Tags: geoserver, postgresql

I've got a postgresql table that has the following attributes:

```
name        String
begintime   String
endtime     String
the_geom    Point
```

Now I'd like to create an sql view in geoserver (2.2 snapshot). In short, i only want to map the features where begintime equals a certain param. Looking at the [geoserver documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html) and the questions here at the forum, I came up with this:

```
select name, begintime, endtime, the_geom 
from n80_tellingen_merge 
where begintime = %utct%
```

This gets me the following error:

```
ERROR: syntax error at or near ")" Position: 111
```

So basically I'm asking two things:

- What am I doing wrong?
- Since I don't have brackets or more than 111 positions, where can I find the actual query sent to postgresql? Can I consult a log somewhere? (Ubuntu server 13.04)

My apolagies if I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure exactly what you want to return from your query. If you want an exact match to a string then you need to wrap the string in single quotes, i.e.

```
select name, begintime, endtime, the_geom 
from n80_tellingen_merge 
where begintime = '%utct%'
```

This will return all records where beingtime is exactly %utct%.

If you want to return records which contains the string 'utct' then you need to use the like parameter:

```
select name, begintime, endtime, the_geom 
from n80_tellingen_merge 
where begintime like '%utct%'
```

See the [PostgreSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html) docs for more details on pattern matching.

Comment: Ok, thank you for that. The sql view now validates, however when requesting http://10.132.32.242:8080/geoserver/wl/wms?service=WMS&version=1.1.0&request=GetMap&layers=wl:tellingen_new&styles=&bbox=5.305280685424805,50.903778076171875,5.343904495239258,50.929527282714844&width=512&height=341&srs=EPSG:4326&format=application/openlayers&viewparams=utct:"2013-03-05T15:00:00Z" i get "Internal error occurred java.io.IOException null Invalid value for parameter utct". I'm sure this value for utct exists, so I'm probably specifying the string wrong in viewparams. I tried using ', " and no brackets...

Answer (score 1):

As begintime is defined as String, you must close your variable into quotation marks:

```
begintime='%utct%'
```

Compare with the code in the [GeoServer documentation](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html#creating-a-sql-view).